# levelDb put call not storing complex Json object properly

Tags: blockchain, leveldb

I am trying to create a private blockchain using LevelDb and having some issues storing complex json object in levelDb.

If i try to save simple string or number as a value, it works, but when i try to store a complex object like mentioned below, while retrieving it always giving me [object Object]. Please see code below.

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    this.level = require('level')

    // 1) Create our database, supply location and options.
    //    This will create or open the underlying store.
    this.db = this.level('my-db')

}

    test() {
        const self = this;
        // 2) Put a key & value
        self.db.put('name', {
            a: 123,
            b: 234,
            c: {
                d: 'dddddd'
            }
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // some kind of I/O error

            // 3) Fetch by key
            self.db.get('name', function (err, value) {
                if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // likely the key was not found

                // Ta da!
                console.log('name=' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))); // Does not work shows [object Object]
                // console.log('name=' + JSON.stringify(value)); // Does not work shows [object Object]            
                // console.log('name=' + JSON.parse(value)); // Does not work shows ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
            })
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it by using JSON.stringify(complexJsonObject) with put call like this

```
test() {
    const self = this;
    // 2) Put a key & value
    self.db.put('name', JSON.stringify({
        a: 123,
        b: 234,
        c: {
            d: 'dddddd'
        }
    }), function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // some kind of I/O error

        // 3) Fetch by key
        self.db.get('name', function (err, value) {
            if (err) return console.log('Ooops!', err) // likely the key was not found

            // Ta da!
            console.log('name=' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))); // Does not work shows [object Object]
            // console.log('name=' + JSON.stringify(value)); // Does not work shows [object Object]            
            // console.log('name=' + JSON.parse(value)); // Does not work shows ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use db.put and db.get with option `valueEncoding` like:

```
db.put('test', [{"data": "test"}], {valueEncoding: "json"}).then(() => {
   db.get('test', {valueEncoding: "json"}).then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log(typeof res)
   })
})
```